# Downloading mass '.txt' from website

Tags: windows-8, download

I am trying to download a bunch of (lets say .txt files) from a website, now they're not very big (about 4-10kbs each) but there are about 70000 of them.

All I am after is the .txt, I don't want to clone the site like HTTrack etc...

Are there any programs out there which would help me out with this problem? ( and save me a ton of time!)

Cheers

Comment: Try `wget` for example. You should include further info into your question, how one can determine the names of the txt-files. And which OS you are using.

Comment: Sorry I am using Windows 8 atm (forgot to say in the above) The .txt files are also on random pages within the site (also they have random names) I should of said this also in the above... sorry and thanks for the reply

Comment: [There's wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: visit `wget` man page, http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html, and look for `acclist`.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look, I was after something like this for files other than images http://www.exisoftware.com/news/download-all-images-from-a-website.html

Comment: if you read the man page it will tell you `wget` can pull more than just images.

Comment: Aye reading now, I am not very good at commands but still reading

Comment: Hmm this looks/sounds abit too complicated for me.

Comment: Even though [much fun has been made of it's UI](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/this-is-what-happens-when-you-let-developers-create-ui.html), [wGetGUI](http://www.jensroesner.de/wgetgui/) (which now includes a "Simple" mode in response) may help you use wget. The Accept List parameter graphicsman mentioned is a set of simple checkboxes (with one for .TXT) and I guess the rest shouldn't be that hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a browser, you can use Firefox with the [DownThemAll extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). You'll need to browse to the root of the directory and launch DownThemAll - you can filter just .txt files on the selection screen.

Comment: I'm not sure downthemall would be a good solution if they are spread out through a site because the OP has stated there are 700 txt files.  Unless there is some option I am unfamiliar with please edit your post with an example.

Comment: Wouldn't this take me just as long? I would have to vist each page (all 50000 of them)?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise they were spread across multiple pages. DTA would have worked if the files in question were centrally indexed/listed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the free [HTTrack website copier](http://www.httrack.com/). It lets you configure e.g. link depth, max file size, bandwith, include and exclude links etc.
"It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure."

Comment: So how would the OP use HTTrack to download *only* the TXT files spread across the site? He has clearly stated he doesn't want to mirror the entire site.

Comment: You're right, he cannot 'just' download the .txt because he needs the 'intermediate' .html too to gather the links. But that's as easy as afterwards "del *.html /s" (and a few more) or an xcopy of all *.txt files to another location. I've done this plenty times for other file types.